# Suppress a text object if embedded summary field has a certain value in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, suppress, crystal-reports-2016

How do you suppress a text object in Crystal if a summarize field inside the text object is equal to 0?

Example of text object content:

[image: Example of summarize field in text object]

I want the text object to only display when {Sum of RETOUR_INVOICE_LINE.AMOUNT_EUR} is zero.
It seems I can't select a summary field in the suppress formula editor.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a bool formula to be true or false using an if statement in the formula, then you can drop the new formula into the suppression for the field in question.

So a formula similar to this, lets call it fBool_IsZero

```
if  {Sum of RETOUR_INVOICE_LINE.AMOUNT_EUR} = 0 then True else False
```

Then use fBool_IsZero in the suppression shown in your question.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, but I get an error when trying to use {Sum of RETOUR_INVOICE_LINE.AMOUNT_EUR} in a formula, it says "This field name is not known".

Comment: Is the SUM a field in use on the report? If not, you'll need to create this and suppress it somewhere, then you should be able to select the Sum field when expanding the '+ Report Fields' when creating the formula

Comment: I got it working now, added the SUM field a second time in the report, this time outside the textbox, and suppressed it like you suggested. Then I was finally able to select that field in the suppress formula of the textbox, by expanding the '+ Report fields' like you suggested.
The resulting suppress formula looks like this:
Sum({RETOUR_INVOICE_LINE.AMOUNT_EUR}, {INCOMING_INVOICE.INCOMING_INVOICE_SEQ}) = 0. Didn't need boolean formula eventually but you put me in the right direction, I'll accept your answer, thanks!